# how to populate class summary field on package information page (package-info.java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have created a javadoc using eclipse and the package information is contained in 
**package-info.java**. my problem is in the class summary field the name of the class is mentioned but there is no detail in front of it.I want to put some information in this field.
This is the javadoc page where package details are mentioned.

[image: this is the screenshot]

package-info.java

```
/**
*
*Details
*/

package mypackage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put the Javadoc comment above the class declaration (See below). See the following [Javadoc tutorial](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs240ta/fall2012/tutorials/javadoctutorial.html) for a quick guide to providing some of these descriptions and other metadata throughout your source code.

```
/**
 * My class description
 */
public class SSOhandler {

}
```

Comment: This link can also be useful http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#descriptions

Comment: i have done that in my original source file but this is not the javadoc page for class it is for the package information. This page contains the package details not the class details.

Comment: Did you regenerate the Javadoc for all of the files (including the package files)? The class details are pulled into that page and as mentioned in the link provided by @HassanTM it uses the first line of the comment for that. `The Javadoc tool copies this first sentence to the appropriate member, class/interface or package summary.`

Comment: It was a mistake made by me.my first line was "@author myname" and then i had given the class details.Its working fine now.Please give an answer so that i can accept it